# Is it possible for me to use a variable in a CREATE TABLE statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, create-table

I would like to do something like the following...

```
declare @tableName as varchar(100)

set @tableName = 'MyNewTable'

CREATE TABLE @tableName
(
column1 int identity(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
column2 varchar(50) not null,
column3 datetime
)
```

...to parameterize the table name in a `CREATE TABLE` statement; but when I run this as-is, I get the error *Incorrect syntax near '@tableName'.*

How can I use a variable in my `CREATE TABLE` statement?

Answer (score 2):

For that you should use dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @tableName AS VARCHAR(100),
        @sql       NVARCHAR(max)

SET @tableName = 'MyNewTable'
SET @sql ='CREATE TABLE ' + @tableName
          + ' ( column1 int identity(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, column2 varchar(50) not null, column3 datetime )'
print @sql
EXEC Sp_executesql
  @sql
```

Comment: You *can* use dynamic SQL, but whether you should is a different question, the answer to which really depends on the situation.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this without dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @tableName as varchar(100)

SET @tableName = 'MyNewTable'
CREATE TABLE TestTemp ( column1 int identity(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, 
                        column2 varchar(50) not null, 
                        column3 datetime )
EXEC sp_rename TestTemp , @tableName
```

Comment: I really like this as a way to sidestep dynamic SQL altogether.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your needs, you can also use a [SQLCMD variable](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/06/28/sql-server-how-to-set-variable-and-use-variable-in-sqlcmd-mode/) to parameterize a table name in a `CREATE TABLE` statement - for example:

```
:setvar tableName "MyNewTable"

CREATE TABLE $(tableName)
(
column1 int identity(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
column2 varchar(50) not null,
column3 datetime
)
```

The potential benefit of this approach (depending on your situation) is *being able to specify the table name with a [`sqlcmd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx) command-line argument* - i.e. `sqlcmd.exe [...] -v tableName="MyNewTable"` (in which case you would comment out the `:setvar` command in the script - since the command-line arg will declare and initialize the expected `tableName` SQLCMD variable).